# How can I save a company model before registration using devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a company model with name:string address:string phone:string with many users relationship.

I also have a user model from devise with email:string password:string and com_id:integer with has one company relationship.

When the new user register, before creating the user, I want to create a company first with name:email from registration and address:"to update" and phone: "to update". So a new company got created and I want to use newly created id in creating the new user with com_id:newly_created_company_id and complete the registration process.
But I do not know how to implement that. Pls help me thanks.

Comment: You need a has_many users on the company model and a company_id:integer on the user model with a belongs_to, then you accept nested attributes for the user on the Company.rb model and you learn how to do proper one to many relationships in rails, a very old railscast might help you here but bear in mind some syntax has changed but you will get the idea especially when it comes to associating the two models, i.e., user.build_company is your friend http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 0):

In the routes, I changed as follows.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
resources :friends
get 'home/about'
root 'home#index'
# Define your application routes per the DSL in 
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

# Defines the root path route ("/")
# root "articles#index"
end
```

And then I created registrations_controller as follow

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

private

def sign_up_params

@company = Company.new(name: "#{params[:user][:email]}")
@company.save
params[:user][:company_id] = @company.id
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
:company_id)
end

end
```

After that I can sign in

> irb(main):012:0> Company.all    Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT
> "companies".* FROM "companies"    =>    [#<Company:0x000001cd7eebc218
> id: 8,   name: "smt@mail.com",   address: nil,   phone: nil,
> created_at: Sat, 02 Apr 2022 08:10:54.234629000 UTC +00:00,
> updated_at: Sat, 02 Apr 2022 08:10:54.234629000 UTC +00:00>]
> irb(main):013:0> User.all   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM
> "users"   => [#<User id: 1, email: "smt@mail.com", created_at:
> "2022-04-02    08:10:54.603527000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-04-02
> 08:10:54.603527000 +0000",    company_id: 8>]   irb(main):014:0>

But the browser is warning me like that. So I think something is wrong???

[image]